# Is it possible to add some funtctionality for all classes by path in war?

Tags: java, aspect

I'm looking for an `AspectJ` (or something else, if you know another way to do that) solution for changing the functionality for all methods satisfying the pattern `get*`.

Is it possible to do that for all classes in `WEB-INF/classes` for entire deployable `war` archive without **explicitly specifying any class with annotation or something else**, because in the project we have too much classes to mark all their manually. It's totatlly unacceptable.

I need to put the line `Logger.applyLogging(this.getClass());` at the beginning of all those methods.

Comment: @duffy356 Yes, I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an AroundAdvice for all getters in that specific package.

To do so you need 2 pointCuts - one for all methods in the package, combined with all methods starting with get in this package.

Then code your aroundAdvice.

Thats some pseudo code:

```
@Pointcut("within(com.xyz.someapp.trading..*)")
public void thePackagePointCut()

@Pointcut("execution(* get*(..))")
public void allGetters()

@Before("thePackagePointCut() && allGetters()")
public void applyAdvise(JoinPoint jp) {
    // Log before invocation

    // let the pointCut execute the method
}
```